# DataTable sort by date in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with sorting my date column in the **datatable** from my web application that I'm working on so this is the data showing at the first access to the app :
[image: LISTFAC.cshtml]
now when I try to sort the **datatable** by `Date Creation` column ascending look how they sorted it :
[image: LISTFAC.cshtml ASC]
and when I click again on the same column this is what I got :
[image: LISTFACT.cshtml DESC]
and this is not matching the sorted values into my Oracle database.
this is my **LISTFACT.cshtml** view code :

```js
var demo = function () {
                datatable = $('#json_data').KTDatatable({
                    // datasource definition

                    data: {
                        type: 'remote',
                        source: '/FactureCLIENT/GETLIST_FACTURE',
                        pageSize: 10,
                    },

                    // layout definition
                    layout: {
                        scroll: false, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
                        footer: true // display/hide footer
                    },
                    sortable: true,
                    height: 300,
                    pagination: true,
                    footer: false,
                     // columns definition
                    columns: [
                        
                        {
                            field: 'NUM_FAC',
                            title: 'NUM Facture',
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'RaisonSocial',
                            title: 'Raison Social',
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'DATE_CRE',
                            title: 'Date Creation',
                            
                           
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'Actions',
                            title: 'Actions',
                            sortable: false,
                            width: 110,
                            autoHide: false,
                            overflow: 'visible',
                            template: function (row) {
                                return '\
                                 <div class="dropdown">\
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                                        <i class="la la-cog"></i>\
                                    </a>\
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">\
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" id="Download"   data-id=' + row.NUM_FAC + '><i class="la la-print"></i> Download PDF</a>\
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" id="DownloadEXL"  data-id=' + row.NUM_FAC + '><i class="la la-print"></i> Download Excel</a>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" id="Supprimer" title="Supprimer" data-id=' + row.NUM_FAC + '>\
                                    <i class="la la-trash"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" id="Edite" title="Edite" data-id=' + row.NUM_FAC + '>\
                                    <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                                </a>\
                                ';
                            },
                        }],

                });
             };
```

and this is my **Controller.cs** code :

```
public ActionResult GETLIST_FACTURE()
    {
        LIST_ENT_FAC model = new LIST_ENT_FAC();

        model.GetFACTUR_LIST(MY_CON);

        
        return new CustomJsonResult() { Data = (model.List_FAC) };

    }
```

and this is my **Model.cs** code :

```
public class LIST_ENT_FAC
{
    public List<ENT_FACTURE_CLIENT> List_FAC { get; set; }

    internal void GetFACTUR_LIST(OracleConnection mY_CON)
    {
        this.List_FAC = new List<ENT_FACTURE_CLIENT>();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select Z_VTL_FAC_CLI_ENT.NUM_FAC ,Z_VTL_FAC_CLI_ENT.\"rais_soc\"  , Z_VTL_FAC_CLI_ENT.DAT_CRE from Z_VTL_FAC_CLI_ENT order by DAT_CRE desc", mY_CON);
        mY_CON.Open();
        OracleDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            this.List_FAC.Add(new ENT_FACTURE_CLIENT
            {
                NUM_FAC = read.GetString(0),
                RaisonSocial = read.GetString(1),
                DATE_CRE = read.GetDateTime(2),
                TEXT_DATE_CRE = read.GetDateTime(2).ToString()
            });
        }
        read.Close();
        mY_CON.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column `DAT_CRE` in the database?

Comment: the data type of `DAT_CRE` is `DATE` and the size = `7`

Comment: I wonder if it is sorting on `TEXT_DATE_CRE` instead of  `DAT_CRE`. Could you format `TEXT_DATE_CRE` like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" (MM=month, HH=24-hour time), just for a test?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have tried it but nothing happend

`while (read.Read())
    {
        DateTime date = read.GetDateTime(2);
        string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        this.List_FAC.Add(new ENT_FACTURE_CLIENT
        {
            NUM_FAC = read.GetString(0),
            RaisonSocial = read.GetString(1),
            DATE_CRE = date,
            TEXT_DATE_CRE = formattedDate
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Hello `stackoverflow` **Dev's community**, I finally found a solution for the DataTable sorting by **date** column:

in my **Controller** code I have this methode to get the data from the **Model** `GetFACTUR_LIST` :

```
public ActionResult GETLIST_FACTURE(){
    LIST_ENT_FAC model = new LIST_ENT_FAC();
    model.GetFACTUR_LIST(MY_CON);
    return new CustomJsonResult() { Data = (model.List_FAC) };
}
```

so in the `CustomJsonResult()` object that contain the serialized **JSON call** I found the error of the **_dateFormat** retrieved incorrectly so I used to modify the format.

from this : `private const string _dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";` 
to this : `private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";`

and this is how I get a solution for my problem.

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            // Using Json.NET serializer
            var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
            isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
        }
    }
}
```